# Windows Phone 7 ListPicker InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a problem building a simple crud form in WP7. I have spent a lot of time to display an Enum into a listpicker an now I see InvalidCastException when trying to bind to the (IsolatedStorage) object.

```
public class Bath {
   public string Colour { get; set; }
   public WaterType WaterType { get; set; }
}

public enum WaterType {
   Hot,
   Cold
}
```

The enum is bound to a ListPicker, but as there is not enum.GetValues() in WP7 this is not a simple task.

I have a simple type class...

```
public class TypeList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my viewmodel, I have ObservableCollection and mock the values from the enum...

```
    private ObservableCollection<TypeList> _WaterTypeList;
    public ObservableCollection<TypeList> WaterTypeList
    {
        get { return _WaterTypeList; }
        set
        {
            _WaterTypeList= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("WaterTypeList");
        }
    }

    public void LoadCollectionsFromDatabase()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TypeList> wTypeList = new ObservableCollection<WaterTypeList>();
        wTypeList.Add(new TypeList{ Name = WaterType.Hot.ToString() });
        wTypeList.Add(new TypeList{ Name = WaterType.Income.ToString() });
        WaterTypeList = new ObservableCollection<TypeList>(wTypeList);
    }
```

Finally, my xaml contains the listbox...

```
<toolkit:ListPicker
            x:Name="BathTypeListPicker"
            ItemsSource="{Binding WaterTypeList}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Im not sure if the above is best practise and indeed if the above is part of the problem but the above does give me a populated ListPicker.

Finally, when the form is submitted the cast causes a InvalidCastException.

```
 private void SaveAppBarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xyz = WaterTypeList.SelectedItem; // type AppName.Model.typeList

        Bath b = new Bath
        {
            Colour = ColourTextBox.Text ?? "Black",
            WaterType = (WaterType)WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem
        };

        App.ViewModel.EditBath(b);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Somewhere.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced a simlar problem and can offer advice. I see that my opions are to concentrate on casting something meaningful from the ListPicker or should I rethink the way that the ListPicker is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem` is an object of type `TypeList` so it can't be cast to an object of type `WaterType`.

In order to convert back to a WaterType, you could replace your cast:

```
WaterType = (WaterType)WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem
```

with:

```
WaterType = (WaterType)Enum.Parse(
                               typeof(WaterType),
                               ((TypeList)WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem).Name,
                               false)
```

Comment: Thats awesome, genuine thanks for this as I was well and truly stuck!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, WaterTypeList is an ObservableCollection that is a Type of  and  an observable collection doesn't have a SelectedItem property.

Your Bath class has a WaterType that accepts WaterType property and you are trying to cast a WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem to it.. so I'm assuming your WatertypeListPicker is your ListBox?

If it is, then you are doing it wrong because your ListBox's itemssource is bound to a  class and you are trying to add a  to your WaterType Property.

What I would do is say,

```
Bath b = new Bath
        {
            Colour = ColourTextBox.Text ?? "Black",
            WaterType = WaterTypeListPicker.SelectedItem
        };
```

Either change my property of Bath's **WaterType** to a **TypeList** so the above code would work. But I won't recommend doing another class to wrap the enum just to show it to the listbox.

What I would do is create an EnumHelper

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetEnumValues<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Type '" + type.Name + "' is not an enum");

        return (
          from field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
          where field.IsLiteral
          select (T)field.GetValue(null)
        ).ToArray();
    }

    public static string[] GetEnumStrings<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Type '" + type.Name + "' is not an enum");

        return (
          from field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
          where field.IsLiteral
          select field.Name
        ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And Bind it to a Collection

My **ViewModel**

```
public IEnumerable<string> Priority
        {
            get { return EnumExtensions.GetEnumValues<Priority>().Select(priority => priority.ToString()); }

public string SelectedPriority
        {
            get { return Model.Priority; }
            set { Model.Priority = value; }
        }
```

Like that.

My **XAML**.

```
<telerikInput:RadListPicker SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Priority}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
```